# sbt-assembly : including test classes

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-assembly

As part of sbt-assembly I want to include both src and test class files in jar. Sbt-assembly includes only src files with dependencies. Is there any way through which I can include test classes also in same jar?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I wrote sbt-assembly so that the settings can be loaded into other configurations than the default `Runtime`. Put the following in `assembly.sbt` and it should add `test:assembly` task:

```
import AssemblyKeys._

Project.inConfig(Test)(baseAssemblySettings)

jarName in (Test, assembly) := s"${name.value}-test-${version.value}.jar"
```

Like the way `jarName` setting is scoped, substitute `xxx in assembly` in README with `xxx in (Test, assembly)` to customize the setting.

Comment: Hi folks, I am having error: not found: object AssemblyKeys error when I run sbt test:assembly, any hint about how to solve this issues?

Comment: I had to follow the solution here instead to make this work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34910525/1571826