# How to include test classes and test dependencies in sbt asssembly

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-assembly

I need to package my test classes, resources and also test dependencies with sbt assembly.

This question [sbt-assembly : including test classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20488329/sbt-assembly-including-test-classes) didn't help - test:assembly still didn't generate a jar with any of the desired classes included.

Note that my setup currently looks like this:

FooBuild.scala:

```
lazy val cucumberAssemblySettings = assemblySettings ++ Seq(
    mainClass in assembly := Some("cucumber.api.cli.Main"),
    jarName   in assembly := "cucumber.jar",
    mergeStrategy in assembly := {
      case "application.conf"     => MergeStrategy.concat
      case "logback.xml"          => MergeStrategy.last
      case x                      => defaultMergeStrategy(x)
    }
  )
```

And it's about the subproject `foo-cucumber`:

```
lazy val foo_cucumber = Project("foo-cucumber", file("foo-cucumber"))
    .settings(defaultSettings: _*)
    .settings(cucumberAssemblySettings: _*)
    .dependsOn(
      foo_test_server % "compile->compile;test->test",
      foo_test_utils % "compile->compile;test->test"
    )
```

even if I append `(Test, assembly)` in the settings above, I only get a jar (whose name is not the one specified, but the full name, with version) that does not contain test classes or dependencies, no matter whether I invoke `sbt foo-cucumber/test:assembly` or `sbt foo-cucumber/assembly`

How do I get a jar that has everything in it (compile and test classes and dependencies)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key for the multi-module project is to set the settings this way:

```
.settings(inConfig(Test)(cucumberAssemblySettings): _*)
```

and then **not** have any `in (Test, assembly)` in the settings

Comment: I tried this way, however, I still cannot find the compiled test classes in the jar file. Do you mind posting your modified build.sbt? Thanks

Comment: you have to run `test:assembly`. There is no other modifiication to the file