# sbt-assembly include test classes

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-assembly

I follow [sbt-assembly : including test classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20488329/sbt-assembly-including-test-classes) from a config described in https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly that work ok doing assembly

When I load sbt I get

```
assembly.sbt:5: error: reference to jarName is ambiguous;
it is imported twice in the same scope by
import sbtassembly.AssemblyKeys._
and import _root_.sbtassembly.AssemblyPlugin.autoImport._
jarName in (Test, assembly) := s"${name.value}-test-${version.value}.jar"
^
```

So, I comment import line and run sbt:assembly but that begin the test but dont generate any *-test-*.jar.

Any one know how to generate the jar that include the test classes?
Thanks

Answer (score 6):

I had to remove this line (I think it is now autoimported based on https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly/blob/546d200477b64e2602beeb65bfa04306122cd9f5/Migration.md)

```
import sbtassembly.AssemblyKeys._
```

And I added the rest (i.e. the two lines below) to **build.sbt** instead of **assembly.sbt**:

```
Project.inConfig(Test)(baseAssemblySettings)
jarName in (Test, assembly) := s"${name.value}-test-${version.value}.jar"
```

After taking those steps, **test:assembly** does produce a test jar for me <strike>however I expected the jar to only include test classes (similar to **test:package**), but it seems to include non-test classes as well.  In other words, if I have **src/main/scala/Foo.scala** and **src/test/scala/FooTest.scala** then I thought that the jar produced by **test:assembly** would only include **FooTest.class** but it seems to also include **Foo.class**.  Hopefully that's not an issue for you as I'm not yet sure how to workaround that.</strike>

**EDIT:** If you want the jar to only include classes from **src/test** (like I did), then you can add the following to your build.sbt to filter out everything else that may be on your classpath:

```
fullClasspath in (Test, assembly) := {
  val cp = (fullClasspath in (Test, assembly)).value
  cp.filter({x => x.data.getPath.contains("test-classes")})
}
```

Comment: In the latest sbt, this works `Project.inConfig(Test)(baseAssemblySettings)`. Of course, I didn't want to skip other classes so didn't try the remaining part.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
lazy val root = project.settings(
    assembly / fullClasspath := (assembly / fullClasspath).value ++ (Test / fullClasspath).value
)
```

Comment: Then how you run the test jar file?