# Scala: Package test from multiple sub projects

Tags: scala, sbt, scalatest

There is a very large Scala project with many sub projects, assume there are 4 sub projects only: project-a, project-b, project-c, project-d.

Project structure is standard, something like:

```
$ tree project-a
├── project-a.sbt
├── src
│   ├── main
│   │   ├── resources
│   │   └── scala
│   └── test
│       ├── resources
│       └── scala
```

I want to package the tests of sub projects into a single jar file so that I can run the tests later.

1. How to package tests of all sub projects into a single jar?
2. How to package tests of some sub projects into a single jar? For example: project-a, project-b only?

Thanks and appreciate all the supports.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sbt-assembly include test classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31427399/sbt-assembly-include-test-classes)

Comment: I guess it might be one option but the seems the answer is an old version of sbt-assembly, I tried but not success yet. Could you please give more detail instruction with later version of sbt and scala?